# Angular Javascript animation works with ng-if but not ng-show

Tags: angularjs, ng-animate, ng-show

I've been experimenting with angular animations and have come to the conclusion that Angular JavaScript based animations are not triggered using ng-if.  I developed a simple Plunkr demonstrating the inconsistency.  Essentially, the problem with this is I don't want to be appending and removing elements from the DOM (ng-if) and would rather use ng-show because one of the items being animated is an HTML5 video that I would like to begin pre-loading upon page load.  The code from the Plunkr is as follows:

HTML

```
<button ng-click="on4=!on4">JS If Transition</button>
<div class="js-if-element" ng-if="on4">I'm animated by JS and ng-if</div>

<button ng-click="on5=!on5">JS Show Transition</button>
<div class="js-show-element" ng-show="on5">I'm animated by JS and ng-show</div>
```

JS

```
app.animation('.js-if-element', function() {
  return {
    enter : function(element, done) {
      element.css('opacity',0);
      jQuery(element).animate({
        opacity: 1
      }, done);

      return function(isCancelled) {
        if(isCancelled) {
          jQuery(element).stop();
        }
      }
    },
    leave : function(element, done) {
      element.css('opacity', 1);
      jQuery(element).animate({
        opacity: 0
      }, done);

      return function(isCancelled) {
        if(isCancelled) {
          jQuery(element).stop();
        }
      }
    }
  }
});

app.animation('.js-show-element', function() {
  return {
    enter : function(element, done) {
      element.css('opacity',0);
      jQuery(element).animate({
        opacity: 1
      }, done);

      return function(isCancelled) {
        if(isCancelled) {
          jQuery(element).stop();
        }
      }
    },
    leave : function(element, done) {
      element.css('opacity', 1);
      jQuery(element).animate({
        opacity: 0
      }, done);

      return function(isCancelled) {
        if(isCancelled) {
          jQuery(element).stop();
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Now if you execute the code in this Plunkr the element with the ng-if directive will animate it's opacity while the element with the ng-show will not trigger the animation.  Also, in the Plunkr I've tested both scenarios using keyframes/CSS transitions and both ng-show and ng-if work http://plnkr.co/edit/yzXYJnMrvYkWBnMtMLAm?p=preview

Comment: enter/leave doesn't even get called which is bizarre. Could be a bug in angular?

Answer (score 3):

I know this is old, but incase others find it show and hide don't use enter leave. You'll have to use `beforeAddClass` and `beforeRemoveClass`.